# Posted data contains only null values in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

the problem is whenever i try to save the data using the view. I always get null data. Please help. My codes for controller, models and view are as follows. Thanks.

```
public class OverallData
{
    public List<UserInfo> userInfo = new List<UserInfo>();
    public UserActivity userActivity = new UserActivity ();
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public action UserName { get; set; }
    public action UserPassword { get; set; }

}

public class UserActivity
{
     public int ActivityID{ get; set; }
     public string ActionPerformed { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model BusinessProcess.Models.OverallData
<h1>List of Usernames</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.userInfo) 
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
}


<h1>Enter some action Performed</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUserActivity", "ManageUser", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditUserActivity" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userActivity.ActionPerformed)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userActivity.ActionPerformed)

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string EditUserActivity(UserActivity tempUserActivity)
{
    string postedValue = tempUserActivity.ActionPerformed;
    //When i debug this the "postedValue" is null
}
```

Comment: Hello guys as you all suggested I tried the below code but still no luck.                                                     [HttpPost]
public string EditUserActivity(OverallData overallData )
{
    string postedValue = overallData.userActivity.ActionPerformed;
}

Comment: Have you tried making `OverallData.userActivity` a property instead of a field?

Comment: Updated my answer - it was working when I made a new project and copied your code in.

Answer (score 1):

I think your controller method `EditUserActivity()` should be expecting a parameter of type `OverallData` instead of `UserActivity` based on the model used in the view which may explain why `ActionPerformed` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is of type `BusinessProcess.Models.OverallData` so your action is expecting that type. I'd say you should change your action method to

```
[HttpPost]
public string EditUserActivity(OverallData overallData )
{
    string postedValue = overallData.userActivity.ActionPerformed;
}
```

Comment: Did the same but sitll no luck.

Comment: @user1957354: with this approach, is the entire object null or just some fields?

Comment: The entire object is null.

Answer (score 0):

The model binder is set to be using OverallData.

This is because of name of the input elements in your view.The model binder uses the names of the form elements to bind them to the class you're passing into the controller.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.userActivity.ActionPerformed)
```

This will be generated with the name `userActivity.ActionPerformed`, so the model binding will look to assign it to `userActivity.ActionPerformed`, instead of just to `ActionPerformed`. Since OverallData doesn't have `userActivity.ActionPerformed`, that value doesn't get assigned to anything.

If you just pass in OverallData as your parameter, it'll work.

**Edit:**

Change your view model to look like this:

```
public class OverallData
{
    public OverallData()
    {
        userActivity = new UserActivity();
        userInfo = new List<UserInfo>();
    }
    public List<UserInfo> userInfo { get; set; }
    public UserActivity userActivity { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
  [HttpPost]
  public string EditUserActivity(OverallData tempUserActivity)
   {
     string postedValue = tempUserActivity.userActivity.ActionPerformed;

   }
```